# is there any limit in key and value for hashtables in powershell 5.1?

Tags: json, powershell, hashtable, powershell-5.1

I  am using PowerShell 5.1 and adding the key, value content in hashtables. but I see, it is not adding the complete content in value when the value is too large around 6000 characters. So, my question is:  Is there any limit while we use PowerShell hashtables, if yes, what could be the other way to save the content as key and value pair.

```
    $inputFileJson = @{}
$inputFileJson.Add($config.NAME,$config.VALUE)
$inputFileJson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | Out-File -Encoding utf8 $localDir\"\\input.json\" -Force
```

Comment: AFAIK tThere is no practical limit, other than it has to fit in memory.

Comment: Please add ***to the question***, how you determine "*but I see, it is not adding the complete content in value when the value is too large around 6000 characters*" as that is probably where the real ussue lies.

Comment: _The variable '$config' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set_. Please [edit] the question and add some example to your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There is not a limit to hashtables, but there is a `-Depth 20` limit you defined for how many levels deep `ConvertTo-Json` will convert nested values to JSON-format. You are likely hitting the depth limit, not a content size limit. Once this limit gets hit, the next object will simply be a `.ToString()` representation of the object, and will not delve into further nested values.

You can specify up to 100 levels deep with `ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100`. However, I find that determining how deep my object actually is, determining how much additional depth to account for, etc. is more trouble than it's worth. Unless you *really* need to truncate objects more than a certain level deep, just use `-Depth 100`.

Comment: what could be the maximum depth ?

Comment: 100 is the maximum depth of nested objects it will convert.

Comment: No, I have tried this. There is no improvement while storing the data. It is storing the same data as before (while depth =20)

Comment: Can you explain in your question what the final output looks like? Do you get an error? A reproducible example will help us help you.